# Randomly executing a branch of code one thirds of the time

Tags: php

I have a question. So I have the following code :

```
protected function definir( $ticketInfos )
{
    if($ticketInfos->aInfosTicket["ProbabiliteGain"]>0)
    {
        $ticketInfos->setGainrecup( $this->getGain() );
    }
    else
    {
        $ticketInfos->setGainrecup( 0.0 );
    }
 }
```

`ProbabiliteGain` is a constant witch is equal with 100. I want to make a winning match to be 1/3. So 2 times I want to do : `$ticketInfos->setGainrecup( $this->getGain() )` and 1 time : `$ticketInfos->setGainrecup( 0.0 );` What is the best solution ? Thx in advance

Comment: Hint: generate a random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by using the php rand() function.

Something like this:

```
protected function definir( $ticketInfos )
{
    $randomNumber = rand(1, 3);
    if($randomNumber < 3)
    {
        $ticketInfos->setGainrecup( $this->getGain() );
    }
    else
    {
        $ticketInfos->setGainrecup( 0.0 );
    }
 }
```

If the $randomNumber is 1 or 2, we execute $this->getGain();
If the $randomNumber is 3, we execute the other function.

You can find more information about the PHP rand function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: I tried this solution, not work for me, because I want after all 2 games  : `setGainrecup(0.0)`, in your solution I can get the number 3 after 5 or 7 games

Comment: Your question is 'Randomly executing a branch of code one thirds of the time'. If you want it to be after fixed times, than your code is not random.

Comment: Exist a solution for my problem?

Comment: One way to achieve what you want would be to store the info in $ticketInfos. Then you could do $ticketInfos->getGameNumber. and increment it after the if/else statement

Comment: But another solution? :)